# CREATE VIEW as join between tables with identically named columns

Tags: postgresql, view, dynamic-sql, naming-convention

As the title says, I'd like to create a view from a join between tables which have columns with identical names (surprisingly "`id`").

Postgres doesn't prepend the table name to the result, but for some reason the query works fine, returning multiple columns with the same name and different data.

`CREATE TABLE` is less forgiving, though, and  returns:

> ```
> ERROR: column "id" specified more than once
> ```

Others have suggested `SELECT`ing the columns under a different name (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26834806/postgresql-unable-to-create-view-due-to-duplicate-column)), but there are many columns to both tables.

Do I need to somehow automatically rename / remove the `id` columns (such as [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179648/prepend-table-name-to-each-column-in-a-result-set-in-sql-postgres-specifically)), or is there a better way?

Comment: You need to alias the column names to rename them in the view - there's nothing else you can do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bug in my answer to the question you referenced. While being at it, I improved some other details:

- [Prepend table name to each column in a result set in SQL? (Postgres specifically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179648/prepend-table-name-to-each-column-in-a-result-set-in-sql-postgres-specifically)

If you have many columns and / or for repeated use, I would use dynamic SQL as outlined over there.

If you'd been using a **proper naming convention**, you could avoid most of these cases. Never use `id` as column name, it's too ambiguous as you are just finding out the hard way. I would use `tbl_id` instead, "tbl" being the table name.
Unfortunately, some ORMs work with this anti-pattern.

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

And you do not get any exception for a plain `SELECT` because Postgres does not require distinct column names in a plain `SELECT` (although the usefulness of this is limited beyond ad-hoc queries). Distinct names are required for columns of a table or view, though - even derived tables in subqueries. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-SELECT-LIST)

> Just as in a table, every output column of a `SELECT` has a name. **In a
>   simple `SELECT` this name is just used to label the column for display**,
>   but when the `SELECT` is a sub-query of a larger query, the name is seen
>   by the larger query as the column name of the virtual table produced
>   by the sub-query.

Postgres has no need for distinct *labels*. But actual column names must be distinct to avoid ambiguities.

Comment: Thanks! I agree about the naming convention. Unfortunately this comes from an ETL from another DB, and I've been trying to avoid setting up a transform to drop/rename those "id" columns.

Comment: BTW I wonder why distinct columns aren't required in SELECT. I also noticed JOIN keys are duplicated.

Comment: @Ohad: I added some explanation for that, quoting the manual.

Comment: Too bad I can't upvote your answer twice :)

Comment: While you are correct that using a more verbose name for the column would avoid this problem, there are trade-offs to things like this.  In this _very rare_ case there is an advantage to the verbose name, but it has a cost, especially if your ORM uses "id" by default.  The extra work to specify the verbose name in all cases will be vastly greater than the extra work in this rare case.  You have a personal naming practice that you find works for you—that's great, I'm not trying to talk you out of it.  But when an entire community has a convention, the cost of breaking with it can be very high.

Comment: Also, I would like to suggest that abbreviating words in your names is a much worse anti-pattern.  I cannot count the number of times that I've inherited a codebase and found methods and fields whose purposes were obscured by the fact that the original developer abbreviated words whose full meaning was obvious to him, but which was not obvious to a new person starting to work on that code.   So if you must prepend the table name, please use full words and not abbreviations, as given in the example.

Comment: (Other than my minor nits, I'm upvoting your answers here and on SO as very useful.)